# Which one is (more) correct: "might very easily have had a different result" or "might have very easily had a different result"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is (more) correct?

> might very easily have had a different result

or

> might have very easily had a different result

Comment: What do Google Ngrams for _might very easily have had_ and _might have very easily had_ suggest? And try substituting 'well' for 'very easily'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More correct? Neither, really. Both are perfectly acceptable and essentially equivalent. It's just a matter of personal preference and which one sounds better to the ear, which is a matter of opinion and easily varies from person to person. But in terms of correctness, it's six of one, half dozen of the other.

So:

> ***There's no difference, basically, between the two besides arbitrary word placement.***

In other words:

> ***Besides arbitrary word placement, there's basically no difference between the two.***